# Execution order with apex:composition

Tags: apex, custom-controller

While using apex:composition in Visualforce page and refering to a template page with a different controller compared to page on which template is defined.

Does this follow same execution order defined at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_get_request.htm

In other words, I have Page Abc.page using apex:composition with MyTemplate.page as template. 
What will be the calling sequence for constructor and action parameters defined in Abc.page and MyTemplate.page